# Conversion to and from std::wstring fails

Tags: c++, c++11

ALL,

I am retrieving some data from the db as char * and then convert it to std::wstring, because I need to pass it to the function which takes this type:

```
AddDropTable( m_myconv.from_bytes( catalog_name ).c_str(), m_myconv.from_bytes( schema_name ), /*some other params*/);
```

Inside the AddDropTable I need to convert those back to char * because I need to retrieve more info. So I do:

```
int MyDb::AddDropTable(const std::wstring &catalogName, const std::wstring &schemaName, /*some other params*/)
{
    const char *catalog_name = m_myconv.to_bytes( catalogName.c_str() ).c_str();
    const char *schema_name = m_myconv.to_bytes( schemaName.c_str() ).c_str();
}
```

m_myconv is declared as:

```
std::wstring_convert<std::codecvt_utf8<wchar_t> > m_myconv;
```

What weird is that inside AddDropTable() catalog_name is empty (under the debugger it shows as "") and schema_name is not returned properly (debugger says: "Error reading characters of string").

It is just a back and forth conversion. Why does it fail?

TIA!

Comment: Have you tried actually assigning the data to a `string` rather than a pointer to a temporary?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ```
> const char *catalog_name = m_myconv.to_bytes( catalogName.c_str() ).c_str();
> const char *schema_name = m_myconv.to_bytes( schemaName.c_str() ).c_str();
> ```

Method `std::wstring_convert::to_bytes()` returns data of type `std::wstring_convert::byte_string` (an alias for `std::string`) **by value**.

This means, the right-hand side of your assignments is a **temporary**, which will be destroyed immediately after each statement. `catalog_name` and `schema_name` are now pointers memory, which has already been freed. Using these pointers is **undefined behaviour**.

To fix this, store the result in a string, which will outlive the statement:

```
std::string catalog_name_str = m_myconv.to_bytes( catalogName.c_str() );
std::string schema_name_str = m_myconv.to_bytes( schemaName.c_str() );
```

You could now obtain C-string pointers, and use them within the scope of the function body:

```
const char *catalog_name = catalog_name_str.c_str();
const char *schema_name = schema_name_str.c_str();
```